# cycle of balance_updates for seed_nonce_revelation kind

Tags: rewards

If looking at `chains/main/blocks/667656`, the cycle is `163`.

```
    "level": {
      "level": 667656,
      "level_position": 667655,
      "cycle": 163,
      "cycle_position": 7,
      "voting_period": 20,
      "voting_period_position": 12295,
      "expected_commitment": false
    },
```

I am wondering why the cycle of the reward of seed_nonce_revelation is `162` but the other kind is as same as the current cycle?

```
{
            "kind": "seed_nonce_revelation",
            "level": 665696,
            "nonce": "fe9bcb9cc7e1abecab3de146a3ee71278d14021c8318074ea548380eb412bbdc",
            "metadata": {
              "balance_updates": [
                {
                  "kind": "freezer",
                  "category": "rewards",
                  "delegate": "tz1eEnQhbwf6trb8Q8mPb2RaPkNk2rN7BKi8",
                  "cycle": 162,
                  "change": "125000"
                }
              ]
            }
```

```
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz1Y2bfsQAYHrWZpM1AwomYMw2KEtaJ5VMfU",
            "fee": "2940",
            "counter": "2203181",
            "gas_limit": "15400",
            "storage_limit": "300",
            "amount": "9201",
            "destination": "KT1Hx2eWwG6ctnnP8xMkqQyobh7qFjDqxzE9",
            "metadata": {
              "balance_updates": [
                {
                  "kind": "contract",
                  "contract": "tz1Y2bfsQAYHrWZpM1AwomYMw2KEtaJ5VMfU",
                  "change": "-2940"
                },
                {
                  "kind": "freezer",
                  "category": "fees",
                  "delegate": "tz1eEnQhbwf6trb8Q8mPb2RaPkNk2rN7BKi8",
                  "cycle": 163,
                  "change": "2940"
                }
              ],...
```

Also which cycle can I get the reward of seed_nonce_revelation? should it be `162 + 6`?  Thanks.